# Issue with sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm setting up a SQL to send out an email with a small txt attachment if the conditions are met. It runs fine without any issues when there is no data with the set conditions. But if there is any data, it throws below error:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Failed to initialize sqlcmd
>   library with error number -2147467259.

This is from SQL server 2014 on Windows 2012.

```
declare @input_date DATETIME
select @input_date = getdate()
declare @runquery varchar(300)
set @runquery= 'SELECT CONVERT(INT, XHSHPN) AS Job_Number, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ) - ((1000*(CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ)/1000)))-1, DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ/1000), "1 Jan 1900")), 103) as Date, CONVERT(INT, XHTDAY) as Time FROM <dbname>.<schema name>.<table name> WHERE XHSSTS = 35 AND XHUPMJ = CONCAT((DATEPART(year, @input_date) -1900),(DATEPART(dy, @input_date))) AND XHTDAY < CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108),":","")) - 500'
if exists (SELECT 1 FROM <dbname>.<schema name>.<table name> WHERE XHSSTS = 35 AND XHUPMJ = CONCAT((DATEPART(year, @input_date) -1900),(DATEPART(dy, @input_date))) AND XHTDAY < CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108),':',''))-500)
begin
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'XXXXXX',
@recipients = 'XXXXXXX@XXX.com',@subject='XXX: XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXX XX XXXXXX XX',@body='XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXX XX XXXXXX XX.

XXXXXXXX XXXXX XX XXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XX "XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXX" XXX "XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX" XX XX-XXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX.

"XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXX" to push the XXXX XXXX XXX to see if the XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXXX.',
@query=@runquery,@attach_query_result_as_file=1,@query_result_separator = '|',@query_result_width = 2550,@query_attachment_filename = 'Jobs Waiting List.txt'
end
```

Can anyone please help me what seems to be the issue here.

Comment: there's a good link on troubleshooting this issue. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5552/troubleshooting-sql-server-spsenddbmail-error-failed-to-initialize-sqlcmd-library/

Comment: Amongst other things, your @runquery value string is far too long. It should be defined as at least `varchar(436)` to hold the entire value. [sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) says it can be up to `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, the question has been formatted now Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues are obvious:

1. `declare @runquery varchar(300)` is too small. The SQL query being assigned to it is already 436 characters long so will get truncated. [sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) defines the `@query` parameter as capable of accepting `nvarchar(max)` so try defining it as:

```sql
declare @runquery varchar(max)
set @runquery= 'SELECT CONVERT(INT, XHSHPN) AS Job_Number, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ) - ((1000*(CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ)/1000)))-1, DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ/1000), "1 Jan 1900")), 103) as Date, CONVERT(INT, XHTDAY) as Time FROM <dbname>.<schema name>.<table name> WHERE XHSSTS = 35 AND XHUPMJ = CONCAT((DATEPART(year, @input_date) -1900),(DATEPART(dy, @input_date))) AND XHTDAY < CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108),":","")) - 500'
```

2. The `@input_date` variable is not accessible to @runquery. `sp_send_dbmail` will invoke your query using `SQLCMD` on a separate SPID (database connection), so none of your current variables will be available to it. Try including it in your runquery. The most trivial way for your example would be:

```sql
declare @runquery varchar(max)
set @runquery= 'declare @input_date datetime = getdate(); SELECT CONVERT(INT, XHSHPN) AS Job_Number, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ) - ((1000*(CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ)/1000)))-1, DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, XHUPMJ/1000), "1 Jan 1900")), 103) as Date, CONVERT(INT, XHTDAY) as Time FROM <dbname>.<schema name>.<table name> WHERE XHSSTS = 35 AND XHUPMJ = CONCAT((DATEPART(year, @input_date) -1900),(DATEPART(dy, @input_date))) AND XHTDAY < CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108),":","")) - 500'
```

If you have Database Mail and profiles configured correctly this should get you a result similar to:

```
Mail (Id: 4) queued.
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections, this is now working as expected and emailing the results too. Appreciate it.